# Upload file to file system in grails while using scaffolding to generate controllers and views

Tags: grails, file-upload, scaffolding

I'm using grails 2.2.2 . In my project, I'm scaffolding controllers and views from domain. Now I want to upload the file and store the uploaded file on file system, instead of database. In db, i'm just going to store the location of the uploaded file.

I googled a bit but only found the way to store the uploaded file in db by defining a byte[] property and i don't want to do that. Please tell me how to save the uploaded file on a file system with scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with scaffolding. You'd have to implement an actual action in your controller. So assuming you want to save a file in your save() action:

```
def save() {
   def someFile = request.getFile("someFile")
   // create a new file somewhere to store the uploaded file:
   def file = new File("/some/path/for/file.foo")
   someFile.transferTo(file)
}
```

Obviously, there's better ways to manage that in terms of your paths and probably doing this in a service, etc. But that's the gist and the takeaway is this can't be scaffolded.